# GoAnywhere DB connection issue with ucanaccess driver to connect to MS Access database

Tags: java

I have downloaded ucanaccess driver and placed all the *.jar files into GoAnywhere host location which runs on Linux.

I am trying to create a DB connection from GoAnywhere GUI (via web service in Browser) and getting issue as file doesn't exist.
MS Access db file is residing on a network share, first I tried that but it didn't work.
I mapped that file to a drive letter but same error
Then I copied the .accdb file to my local laptop and gave that path, but get the same error message:

> Error:
> UCAExc:::5.0.0-SNAPSHOT given file does not exist: C:\Users\guptah\Harish_Offshore\BidCost.accdb
>
> JDBC Driver: net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver
> JDBC URL: jdbc:ucanaccess://C:\Users\guptah\Harish_Offshore\BidCost.accdb

File exist at my local machine

```
c:\Users\guptah\Harish_Offshore>dir C:\Users\guptah\Harish_Offshore\BidCost.accdb
 Volume in drive C is OSDisk
 Volume Serial Number is 9285-44B9

 Directory of C:\Users\guptah\Harish_Offshore

02/05/2020  01:14 PM     1,209,655,296 BidCost.accdb
               1 File(s)  1,209,655,296 bytes
               0 Dir(s)  81,508,196,352 bytes free
```